# Does PHP support persistent key-value stores available outside of the session?

Tags: php, key-value

Short question: I need a K/V store for PHP that's scope would not be limited to a particular HTTP session. A RDBMS would be overkill, so I've ruled that out already. It also needs to be available for users of a shared-resource hosting server. Does that exist?

Long question: I'm working on a PHP client library accessing a REST API remotely. I would rather the requests for data be persisted in a K/V-store so that when a predetermined time elapses, the underlying data will be considered "stale" and makes a call to the API (transparently.)

My problem is that I assume that the end-user will not have access to anything outside of the normal shared-resource hosting solutions.

I come from the Java world, BTW.

Comment: [Peruse this list](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php).

Comment: Do you have access to `apc` or `apcu` (some hosting providers do support this on shared hosting boxes).

Comment: I would consider 75% availability in the market usuable. Access for myself is not considered, but for the average developer on a shared-hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

An option for you would be Memcache:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php

Other options might be: Redis, MongoDb or a K/V table in a database (MySQL).

If Memcache is not available (which should be) and the only options you have are MySQL or a file on the disk, I would choose MySQL.

One table: key_values with fields key (primary key), value and expiration date.

You can create a simple PHP class with the methods (example): add, get, update, delete, deleteExpired.

The usage is self explanatory with one mention: you would have to create a script that calls deleteExpired() and ideally runs afterwards the SQL query "OPTIMIZE TABLE key_values".

This script must be set-up as a cron job (set to run automatically every N minutes) - that's quite standard on a shared hosting system.

Comment: These would not likely (except MySQL) be available to a developer on a shared-resource hosting plan. I'm looking more for a library of some sort.

My guess of what it would look like is a key-value store that writes to disk so that any PHP script would be able to read\write to it

Comment: Memcache should be available. But if not, I have enlarged my original answer with a persistent MySQL db example.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the following project: https://github.com/doctrine/cache
It provides a file store implementation.